# Change Link to Upload folder

Tags: uploads

I'm working on a restyling of a wordpress site, which has an upload folder of almost 120gb. I made a copy of the entire site except the upload folder, I would like to avoid it, to make quick copies of testing.

I was looking for a way to link to the Test site, the original upload folder, of the live site.
Is there a way to tell Wordpress to look for the upload folder at another address?

I hope it is clear.
Thank you

Comment: If you're working on a local copy on a Mac, you can use a Valet driver to do this: https://happyprime.co/2022/02/11/how-to-install-wordpress-locally/

Comment: Hi,
no, I made a copy on an online server that I use for testing.
I would like to avoid copying the upload folder and making a link to the original upload folder.